# How to use ajax in field widget form?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax, plugins

I need to store a country and a region for geographical objects. Countries and regions are stored in a taxonomy vocabulary. Moreover, some countries have regions (as child terms) but someones don't have it.

I decided to create a complex field contains tid of a country and tid of a region. If an object doesn't have a set region, then a value of the region is 0 in this case.

I want to create a field widget for it. The widget should contain a combo box with a list of countries. Moreover, if the user is selected a country having regions, then a new combo box with its regions is appeared.

I have tried to do it with ajax like it is done in forms.

That is, I have written the following.
(Here I have removed some code from the source to shorten it)

```
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {

// come code here ....

    // TODO: Implement formElement() method.
    $element['country_id'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Select a country'),
      '#options' => PalomGeo::getCountryList(),
      '#default_value' => $country_id,
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::changeCountry',
      ]
    ];

    $regions = PalomGeo::getRegionList($country_id);

    if ($regions!=[]){
      $element['region_id'] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Select a region'),
        '#options' => $regions,
        '#default_value' => $region_id,
      ];
    }

    return $element;
  }

// Some code here

  public function changeCountry(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    return $form['region_id'];
  }
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work.

The error "The specified #ajax callback is empty or not callable" is appeared.

I want to clarify is it possible to use AJAX upon creating field widgets? If yes, does it differ from using AJAX in Drupal 8 Forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the class (including the full namespace) to run that method on. E.g: `'callback' => \Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\MyWidget::changeCountry`

Comment: For me, this threw an error if changeCountry was declared as in the question: `Deprecated function: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\MyWidget::changeCountry() should not be called statically`. It was easily resolved by changing the callback value to `'callback' => [$this, 'changeCountry']`.